# Push Notifications work from FCM console but if sent from API show “InvalidApnsCredential” error (only on iOS devices)

Tags: ios, firebase, apple-push-notifications, capacitor

Push notification FMC API doesn't work on iOS

I tried to verify my APNS certificates and seems okay

From FMC console testing notifications work and arrive successfully to iOS devices

**Endpoint url**
https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send

**Request headers:**

```
Content-Type:application/json
Authorization:key=**SERVER_KEY**
```

**Request payload body:**

```
{
    "to": "**FMC_DEVICE_TOKEN**",
    "priority": "high",
    "notification": {
        "title": "Title",
        "body" : "First Notification",
        "text": "Text"
    }
}
```

**Response body:**

```
{
    "multicast_id": 6714208302733418144,
    "success": 0,
    "failure": 1,
    "canonical_ids": 0,
    "results": [
        {
            "error": "InvalidApnsCredential"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Same for me, via the firebase console I receive the test notification but as soon as I'm trying with the "notification" property or the "content_available" property I experiment this error. Btw all my certificate are ok. The only thing that changed is the ios version updated this morning from 12.3 to 12.4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is apparently a global issue from Firebase today. Many people have been reporting this error in the past 3 hours. I hope it's gonna be fixed tomorrow.

Comment: Yes I suspected the same, thanks for the feedback. Today is working