# Firebase (FCM) + Laravel | Push Notification error InvalidApnsCredential

Tags: php, swift, apple-push-notifications

I am using LaravelFCM (https://github.com/brozot/Laravel-FCM) package for push notifications. They are working fine on my localhost and my old server. But I recently migrated to new Godaddy Linux server and when I try to send push notification I am getting notifications on android but not on iOS. It gives an error of InvalidApnsCredential.

Push Notifications are successfully sent via firebase console and from my localhost and from old server...no changes to the code is made.

Thank You!

ALREADY TRIED THE FOLLOWINGS:
Downloaded the latest certificates and uploaded them again to the firebase console.
Added Team ID to firebase console
Working fine on Firebase Console, localhost and old server.

Comment: it seems to be a global problem of firebase.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57310186/push-notifications-work-from-fcm-console-but-if-sent-from-api-show-invalidapnsc https://twitter.com/ios_overflow/status/1156946303466844165?s=20

Comment: still facing the same issue :(